# Firestore nested security rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

Could I manage access to nested field with in Firestore with rules?

For example in the Structure

```
users
   b1a2e3
      profile
      rating
      personal_info
```

Could I allow access to personal_info only if `users.uid == request.auth.uid`?

Answer (score 2):

No the rules only apply to collection and documents. You can't take only some data inside a document.

If you want you can't try to change your structure for Something like this with the public info inside the document UserUID.

(collection) User / (doc) UserUID / (collection) private_info

And use this rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

  match /users/{userUID} {

        // Other rules

         match/personal_info/{allChildren=**}{
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
        }
  }
}
```

You have more information about rules on firestore here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#nested_matches

Comment: So if i haven't right to read, i will not even get information that `personal_info` object exists?

Comment: Oh sorry I forget to read the "field" in your question. I will edit my answer